# Change radio button and style it with click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created HTML for changing payment method.

```
<ul id="checkout-method">
    <li><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Cash on Delivery">
        <label>Cash on Delivery</label>
        <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:none">Pay with cash upon delivery.</p>
    </li>
    <li><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Paypal">
        <label>Paypal</label>
        <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:none">Pay via PayPal; you can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a PayPal account.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I do not know how to do :

- Always make first `input` is checked.
- Click on `li` parent tag to check radio instead of radio button.
- If one is check, `.explainpaymethod` will show, other is hide.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: what question should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- To make the first radio checked, use `checked` property in the first input tag.
- To be able to click on `li` parent tag, check radio instead, use `display: block;` property on `<label>`

You can achieve all your properties like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  

 $("input[type='radio']").on('click', function(e) {
   $('p.explainpaymethod').hide();
   if($(this).is(':checked')) {
     $(this).closest('li').find('p.explainpaymethod').show();
    }
  })

});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="checkout-method">
    <li><label><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Cash on Delivery" checked>
        Cash on Delivery</label>
        <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:inline-block">[Pay with cash upon delivery.]</p>
    </li>
    <li><label><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Paypal">
        Paypal</label>
        <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:none">[Pay via PayPal; you can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a PayPal account.]</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. It is helpful. :).

Comment: @MinhAnh - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

> Always make first input is checked.

Use the `checked` attribute in the HTML to set the default selected option.

> Click on li parent tag to check radio instead of radio button.

Don't add the click on the `li`, instead wrap the input and the text in the `<label>` element. This is a standard control which expands the hit area for the radio button.

> If one is checked, .explainpaymethod will show, other is hide.

You will need some JS to do this. You need to hide all the `.explainpaymethod` elements before showing the one related to the changed radio button by using DOM traversal techniques. Specifically `closest()` and `find()`. Try this:

```js
$('#checkout-method input').change(function() {
  $('.explainpaymethod').hide();
  $(this).closest('li').find('.explainpaymethod').show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="checkout-method">
  <li>
    <label>
      <input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Cash on Delivery" checked="true">
      Cash on Delivery
    </label>
    <p class="explainpaymethod">Pay with cash upon delivery.</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>
      <input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Paypal">
      Paypal
    </label>
    <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:none">Pay via PayPal; you can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a PayPal account.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. ! It is so helpful

Answer (score 1):

> 1)Always make first "input" is checked.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').eq(0).prop('checked',true);
```

> 2)Click on li parent tag to check radio instead of radio button.

You need to use `<label for="parent_id">`

```
<label for="Paypal">Paypal</label>
```

> 3)If one is check, `.explainpaymethod` will show, other is hide.

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
   $('.explainpaymethod').hide();
   $(this).closest('li').find('.explainpaymethod').show();
});
```

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').eq(0).prop('checked',true);
$('input[type="radio"]').eq(0).closest('li').find('.explainpaymethod').show();
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {
  $('.explainpaymethod').hide();
  $(this).closest('li').find('.explainpaymethod').show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="checkout-method">
    <li><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Cash on Delivery" id="Cash">
        <label for="Cash">Cash on Delivery</label>
        <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:none">Pay with cash upon delivery.</p>
    </li>
    <li><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Paypal" id="Paypal">
        <label for="Paypal">Paypal</label>
        <p class="explainpaymethod" style="display:none">Pay via PayPal; you can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a PayPal account.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without javascript.

First add checked attribute to the input which you want to be checked by default.

Then add "id" attribute to the inputs and "for" attribute to the labels.

```
<ul id="checkout-method">
    <li><input name="payment_method" type="radio" checked value="Cash on Delivery" id="cod">
        <label for="cod">Cash on Delivery</label>
        <br>
        <p class="explainpaymethod">Pay with cash upon delivery.</p>
    </li>
    <li><input name="payment_method" type="radio" value="Paypal" id="pp">
        <label for="pp">Paypal</label>
        <br>
        <p class="explainpaymethod">Pay via PayPal; you can pay with your credit card if you don’t have a PayPal account.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then add the following CSS which shows paragraph if their sibling input is checked.

```
.explainpaymethod {
  display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .explainpaymethod {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the link to the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u1zjyorf/3/